# Is it possible to return to the same contact summary page (ajax) once we have edited a contribution?

Tags: ajax, summaryfields, datatables

For example, when edit a one contribution in page 10 and save, return to page 10 and not to first page of contributions.

Thanks.

[image: Pagination Contributions]

Comment: I found this var: "crmPID" but i can't change, I need access to this value. For example in "CRM_Contribute_Form_Search". Thanks!